# Node.js/Express: "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'nomeTasks' of 'req.body' as it is undefined"

Tags: javascript, express

I am building a Node.js application with Express, and I have set up a POST route to create tasks. However, I am encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve.

The error message I'm getting is:

```
> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'nomeTasks' of 'req.body' as it is undefined
```

Here's my route code:

```js
router.post("/add_tasks", async (req, res) => {
    const { nomeTasks, status } = req.body; // This line is causing the error
    const novaTasks = await tasksCreate(nomeTasks, status);
    res.status(201).json(novaTasks);
});
```

I'm sending a POST request with the Insomnia tool to `http://localhost:3000/add_tasks`.
The request body in Insomnia is configured as JSON and contains the fields 'nomeTasks' and 'status'.
I have set up `express.json()` middleware in my app.js as follows:

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

Despite checking all these configurations, I still encounter the error. I have also restarted the Node.js server after making changes to the code.

Can anyone help me identify the root cause of this error and suggest potential solutions?

my app.js code looks like this

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const db = require("./config/db");
const tasks = require("./models/taskModel");
const tabelaTasks = require("./db/tabelaTasks");
const routers = require("./routes/taskRoutes");
const controllerCreate = require("./controllers/tasksCreate");
const controllerDelete = require("./controllers/tasksDelete");
const controllerRead = require("./controllers/tasksRead");
const controllerUpdate = require("./controllers/tasksUpdate");

require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3033;

app.use("/", routers);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Bem vindo a todo list ");
});

app.use(routers); // I added the router here

db.sync()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Tabelas sincronizadas com sucesso.");
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log("Servidor rodando na porta " + PORT);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Erro ao sincronizar tabelas:", error);
    });
```

my routes.js code looks like this

```js
// taskRoutes.js

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const tasksCreate = require("../controllers/tasksCreate");
const tasksRead = require("../controllers/tasksRead");
const tasksUpdate = require("../controllers/tasksUpdate");
const tasksDelete = require("../controllers/tasksDelete");

router.post("/add_tasks", async (req, res) => {
    const { nomeTasks, status } = req.body;
    const novaTasks = await tasksCreate(nomeTasks, status);
    res.status(201).json(novaTasks);
});

router.get("/lista_de_tarefas", async (req, res) => {
    const tasks = await tasksRead(); // Correção aqui
    res.status(200).json(tasks);
});

router.put("/atualizar_tarefas/:id", async (req, res) => {
    // Correção aqui
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { nomeTasks, status } = req.body;
    const mensagem = await tasksUpdate(id, nomeTasks, status);
    res.status(200).json({ message: mensagem });
});

router.delete("/apagar_tarefas/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const mensagem = await tasksDelete(id);
    res.status(200).json({ message: mensagem });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and I'm sending the body of the request in Insomnia like this

```json
{
    "nomeTasks": "Aprender a programar",
    "status": "Pendente"
}
```

and here is the complete error

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'nomeTasks' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.
    at C:\Users\eduar\todo_list\routes\taskRoutes.js:10:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\eduar\todo_list\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)    at next (C:\Users\eduar\todo_list\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\eduar\todo_list\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\eduar\todo_list\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)    at C:\Users\eduar\todo_list\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\eduar\todo_list\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)       
    at next (C:\Users\eduar\todo_list\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\eduar\todo_list\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (C:\Users\eduar\todo_list\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

Node.js v18.17.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Based on this,  could help with this error as I'm trying to learn how to program backend

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show where `router` is added to your `app`? It should be **after** `app.use(express.json())`. Please also show how you're sending the request body in Insomnia

Comment: I edited it, see if it's better now

Comment: Not that it really matters but are you using `express.json()` or `bodyParser.json()`? Your question is not consistent

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to register the request body-parsing middleware **before** your routes. You've also registered `routers` twice for some reason